# Use of timer_list in Linux kernel module causes system to crash

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm writing a kernel (2.6.28) module that uses a dynamic timer. I'm using the timer_list structure as follows:

```
struct timer_list our_timer;
init_timer(&our_timer);
our_timer.function = handleFlowTimer;
our_timer.expires = jiffies + 2000;
our_timer.data = 0;
add_timer(&our_timer);

void handleFlowTimer(unsigned long data)
{
    //do nothing
}
```

This works ok for about 2 seconds until the timer expires. Then the system crashes. I've also tried something like this with the same result:

```
struct timer_list our_timer = TIMER_INITIALIZER(handleFlowTimer, 0, 0);
mod_timer(&our_timer, jiffies + 2000);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

`our_timer` is allocated on stack and you pass a pointer to it. It is most probable that `our_timer` gets out of scope, overwritten, and after 2 seconds the value `our_timer.function` is invalid.

Make `our_timer` a `static` variable or use `kmalloc`.